# Journals specializing in point-set topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Are there any scholarly journals specializing in point-set topology? I would like to know which ones. I do not want something that has mostly algebraic topology articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Topology and its Applications*](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/topology-and-its-applications) is one possibility; it has a higher proportion of papers in general and set-theoretic topology than most with which I’m at all familiar, and the current editors-in-chief work in those fields. From the journal’s web site:

> The mathematical focus of the journal is that suggested by the title: Research in **Topology**. It is felt that it is inadvisable to attempt a definitive description of topology as understood for this journal. Certainly the subject includes the **algebraic**, general, **geometric**, and set-**theoretic** facets of topology as well as areas of interactions between topology and other mathematical disciplines, e.g. topological algebra, topological dynamics, functional analysis, category theory. Since the roles of various aspects of topology continue to change, the non-specific delineation of topics serves to reflect the current state of research in topology.